# Play a video with AVPlayer in Swift Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am having trouble playing a video within a swift playground using AVPlayer.

Here's my code.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var f=CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)
var url=NSURL(string: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/vids4project/sample.mp4")
var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

var v = UIView(frame:f)
var player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
var playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

playerLayer.frame=f
v.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

Any suggestions? The code as does nothing at all.  My expectation is the 'v' variable should be showing the video.    It seems to work outside the playground when I am connecting the avplayerlayer to a view from a storyboard.

Answer (score 8):

The following should work if you drop it into a playground. Make sure to swap out the path: (Xcode 11 & Swift Playgrounds Mac & iOS)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import PlaygroundSupport

var playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)

guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "movie", ofType: "m4v") else {
    fatalError("no movie found")
}

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)

var playerView = UIView(frame: playerFrame)
playerView.backgroundColor = .black
var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

playerLayer.frame = playerFrame
playerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = playerView

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Thanks for this! how can you make it so that it keeps playing?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this at the end to keep the playground running

```
import XCPlayground
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks of @Justin Levi Winter's answer and I had updated the code for Swift3, tested with Xcode 8 (This video plays in timeline, but not on the Quick Look):

```
import AVFoundation
import PlaygroundSupport


URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
let width = 568
let height = 320

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


func playVideo(_ url: URL){
    let f=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)

    let player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    playerLayer.frame=f
    container.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container

    player.play()
}

playVideo(URL(string:"http://s3.amazonaws.com/vids4project/sample.mp4")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.*

After reading several answers including the above ones I coded following.
It works but with an issue player view placement a bit off. I mean when x and y values of its frame it should be at upper left corner but it does not sit there. The main issue was how to write url actually by the way.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import AVFoundation
import CoreMedia


class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var mPlayer : AVPlayer?
    var mItem   : AVPlayerItem?
    var playerLayer        : AVPlayerLayer?
    var playerView = UIView()  
  


    override func loadView() {
    
        let view = UIView()
        self.view = view
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000)
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    
        let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 1, y: 10, width: 500, height: 500)
        playerView.frame =  playerFrame
        view.addSubview(playerView)
        playVideo()
   
    }

   func playVideo(){
        let url0 =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("IMG_0626.MOV")
    
    
        mItem                       = AVPlayerItem(url: url0)
        mPlayer                     = AVPlayer(playerItem: mItem!)
        playerLayer                 = AVPlayerLayer(player: mPlayer) 
    
        playerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        playerLayer?.frame          = playerView.bounds
        playerLayer?.videoGravity   = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
        mPlayer?.play()
    }
}



// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try is to use an `AVPlayerView` which can be set as the playground's live view.

```
import Foundation
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import AVFoundation
import AVKit


public func playVideo(at vidURL: URL) -> (AVPlayerView, AVPlayer) {
    print("Playing Video at \(vidURL)")
    let videoFrame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
    let playerView = AVPlayerView(frame: videoFrame)
    
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: vidURL)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    
    playerView.player = player
    
    return (playerView, player)
}

guard let videoURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoFileName, withExtension: "mp4") else {
    fatalError("\(videoFileName) -> Video file not found")
}

let (playerView, videoPlayer) = playVideo(at: videoURL)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = playerView
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

videoPlayer.pause() //videoPlayer.play()
```