# AVPlayerViewController in playground not showing video output in timeline

Tags: swift-playground, avplayerviewcontroller

I have the following playground

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import XCPlayground

let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480)
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)
player.allowsExternalPlayback = false
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = playerViewController.view!
playerViewController.view!.frame = frame
playerViewController.player = player
playerViewController.player!.play()
```

But the time timeline output shows the following:

[image]

I can hear the audio, but no video plays.

What am I doing wrong.  I am using the latest xCode release 7.3

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: This should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945704/play-a-video-with-avplayer-in-swift-playground/42765816#42765816